# c# high multi-layer dictionary convert low multi-layer dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

this main dictionary.
It is a 3rd floor dictionary.

```
/// arc . replaceText.ToLower() , sub , ogg
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>>> listArcSub3;
```

How can I easily switch to the dictionary below?
This is the 2nd floor dictionary

```
/// replaceText.ToLower() , sub , ogg
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>> listSub2;
```

this my code
I want to change from the 3rd floor to the 2nd floor.
Sub-Dictionaries must be merged.
Can you make it short and concise instead of this long code?

```
foreach (var item in listArcSub3)
{
    foreach (var item2 in item.Value)
    {
        // replaceText.ToLower() , sub , ogg
        if (!listSub2.ContainsKey(item2.Key))
        {
            listSub2[item2.Key] = item2.Value;
            continue;
        }

        foreach (var item3 in item2.Value)
        {
            // sub , ogg
            if (!listSub2[item2.Key].ContainsKey(item3.Key))
            {
                listSub2[item2.Key][item3.Key] = item3.Value;
                continue;
            }

            listSub2[item2.Key][item3.Key].UnionWith(item3.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My rule of thumb for these things, generally, is that if you're beyond the "dictionary of dictionaries" level you should switch to something else

Comment: gulp! a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries of hashsets, I have been a professional c# coder for almost 20 years, written many multi 100k line projects, never ever got that complex. You sure thats what you need

Comment: anyway - if that code works I would stick with it, any linq type stuff would be too opaque

Comment: The  main dictionary problem is that it has a key. And without seeing the real data, it is hard to tell what the new key could be